# Is it unprofessional to be the first to leave if I'm first to arrive?

Tags: professionalism, first-job, mexico

I recently graduated and I'm currently working for a development company (This is my first job, I've been working there for about 4 months plus 6 internship months).

We are a small team of 6 members, 2 of us (myself included), arrive at 9:00 am and finish at 7:00 pm (with a 2 hours break in the middle the rest arrive one hour later and also leave 1 hour later.

Most of the time I'm the first one in the office. But only the coworker who shares my schedule notices. Also, most of the time I'm the first one to leave (usually between 7:00 - 7:10 pm), but this time everyone, my boss included, notices).

Given this situation, is it unprofessional for me to be the first one to go home??

Comment: Make sure to mention it to your manager!

Comment: Consult your contract / company handbook / manager / HR to find out or discuss your official working hours. It's not unprofessional to work the hours you agreed to work with your company, it is unprofessional to not work the hours you agreed to work.

Answer (score 1):

First, are you salaried or hourly? Scheduling is important when it comes down to that. If your hourly, and not being paid overtime, you absolutely shouldn't exceed your scheduled time without pay. If your salaried, your job is more "task focused". As long as you can prove your work is being done, and you're following through with your commitments on time, you can justify your hours.

Second, company culture is a large factor. Some companies are focused on the appearance of working hard, some aren't. Some actually require hard work too.

When you say they "noticed" what do you mean? Did they say something snarky? You might just be getting "new guy" treatment.

Comment: I'm paid for working 8 hours a day, 5 days a week. No one has said anything to me (yet, I don't know if the will) I just wanted to mark that there are more people in that can tell I leave early.

Comment: @Guywhotypesfast You're not leaving early. You're leaving on time...

Comment: Exactly what @Maybe_Factor said. You are adhering to your schedule. If your supervisor has issues with it, it is within their control to modify.